# No Footing Under Existing Structure

Tags: foundation

[image].

The entryway has started to detach from my home.  On one side is the entryway and the other a small room.  The floors have started to slant.  One side is worse than the other and one side has started to detach and not he other.  We called a foundation company to repair it.  They came out to repair it and found that there was no footing underneath so, the couldn't do anything.  They referred us to a cement company.  The cement company came out to look at everything.  They were supposed to call us with an estimate but. We never heard from them.  I have posted the information about my issue on several sites that help find contractors and nothing.  Is this typical for the type of job that needs to be done.  Where do you start.  Are we supposed to be looking for a cement company or someone else.  We can't seem to be able to find one.  Our Michigan home was built in 1937.  Any suggestions.

Comment: You need to find a company that has expertise in raising houses and installing foundations. Not all company's will raise homes and the one you contacted may not have the experience or equipment to do the work. Find  several other companies to provide quotes. You may be able to have a footing then block stem wall as an option.

Comment: Is there room under the house that could be used - if yes how much?